# Random white space beneath my website caused by image and video

Tags: javascript, html, css

In between my main body elements and my footer, there is a bunch of random white space in my website. I've figured out that by removing my cat image and videoplayer, the space goes away. But, of course, I don't want to have to do that, so I was wondering what's creating the white space. The only way I've been able to get rid of it is by REMOVING the video and image. Taking away certain css or all of the css doesn't work.

Sorry in advance for posting all of my code, but the problem is only visible when all of my code is there. Posting text or anything else as a replacement for my code doesn't show the problem. Thats why there's so much code there.

```js
function length() {
  var video = document.getElementById("sample");
  len = video.duration;
  document.getElementById("vidlen").innerHTML = len.toFixed(1);
}
```

```css
.videoplayer {
  position: relative;
  right: -400px;
  bottom: 290px;
  width: 35%;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#pgselect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 133.859375px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#catbanner {
  position: relative;
  left: 470px;
  bottom: 260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#EBEDF3;">
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <div class="videoheader">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div style="clear: both;" class="card-header">
          <div style="font-family:'Faster One'; float:left;">Earth Spinning Video</div>
          <div id="vidlen" style="font-family:'Faster One'; float:right;"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="sample" onloadedmetadata="length()" controls enablejavascript="true">
                        <source src="sample.mp4">
                    </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="catbanner" class="card card-body">
    <img src="catbanner.jpg" alt="Four Cats">
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div id="pgselect" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Page 1
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
          <a class="dropdown-item disabled">1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page3.html">3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page4.html">4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true"></audio>
  <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true"></audio>
  <script>
    var death = document.getElementById("death");
    death.volume = 0.2;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE: The cat image and video aren't the actual image and video because they're not in a directory, but when they're full size the white space is more noticable.

[image]

Comment: As I already suggested on another question, please create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can rule out issues caused by the irrelevant code and be able to help you find the problem. You need to help us to help you! Do you *really* need the banner, the nav etc and the associated CSS in order to see the extra space in the footer?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I tried cutting things out before but then you couldn't see the problem. I tried making simpler code to replicate what I had before so I could make the snippet minimal, but it didn't work. That's why I left everything in but specified where I believe the problem is occurring.

Comment: If you would like us to help, then you should make it as easy as possible for us to help! The easier it is for us to find the problem the more likely you are to get an answer. As I said, do you really need the banner, the nav etc and the associated CSS to recreate the problem?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I took out everything other than the things that create the problem. I look forward to your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @FluffyKitten I realized after taking everything out, the problem doesnt exist anymore. I don't know what to do. I can't leave everything in, but I also can't take everything out.

Comment: You *only* take out the stuff that doesn't affect it, like the banner and nav (I assume). But it is still happening in the snippet so that might be enough to work on.

Comment: I don't have the time right now to really dive into this, but generally speaking, when there's white space around (generally underneath) videos and/or images, it's because they aren't `display:block;`

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm not sure what affects it anymore. It is the image and video, as when I remove them from my actual code the problem is solved, but like I said in the post, without my other items, the problem is also solved. I really appreciate your help and sticking with me btw.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I found out my problem exactly but I don't know how to solve it. So the problem is that my webpage is longer than the content inside. I can move things down but then the white space is at the top. I tried to lessen the height of the body, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that there is less code to debug, it is easier to see where the problem is :)

You are setting the `bottom` property for the elements, which is adding that space to the bottom of the container. If you remove this value from the divs, it fixes the problem.

**Note**: You could still have problems due to setting the `right` or `left` on Bootstrap cards. It would be better to just use the Bootstrap classes, without trying to "pull" some elements out of it's layout by specifying their positions.

Mixing custom positioning with Bootstrap like this is going to cause problems. Bootstrap is a complete framework that creates the layout for you - if you make changes to some elements, it is going to have an effect on the overall layout of the page.

**Working Example:**
(I replaced your video and image in the example below so you can see what is happening).

```js
function length() {
  var video = document.getElementById("sample");
  len = video.duration;
  document.getElementById("vidlen").innerHTML = len.toFixed(1);
}
```

```css
.videoplayer {
  position: relative;
  right: -400px;
/*  bottom: 290px;*/
  width: 35%;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#pgselect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 133.859375px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#catbanner {
  position: relative;
  left: 470px;
/*  bottom: 260px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#EBEDF3;">
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <div class="videoheader">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div style="clear: both;" class="card-header">
          <div style="font-family:'Faster One'; float:left;">Earth Spinning Video</div>
          <div id="vidlen" style="font-family:'Faster One'; float:right;"></div>
        </div>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="catbanner" class="card card-body">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400" alt="Four Cats">
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div id="pgselect" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Page 1
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
          <a class="dropdown-item disabled">1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page3.html">3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="page4.html">4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true"></audio>
  <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true"></audio>
  <script>
    var death = document.getElementById("death");
    death.volume = 0.2;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So how can I position things where I want without specifying?

Comment: @meematzzz Let Bootstrap's framework do that for you - that's what it is meant for! Or don't use Bootstrap's framework if you don't want it to create the layout for you.

Comment: Everything was just placed in a line with bootstrap's framework. There's absolutely no way to move bootstrap's elements around? Do I just have to redo most of my entire website?

Comment: @meematzzz Of course not. I presume you picked Bootstrap because it gives you the layout you want. You just need to use the appropriate classes for that layout.  Check the documentation to see what other classes or css you need to include for it to work correctly.